# LLVM Loop Simplify Pass

Tags: loops, clang, llvm, llvm-ir

I am probably misunderstanding some basic concept how LLVM & passes work, anyhow here is my question:

I am currently working on a pass where I extend the runOnModule (https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1ModulePass.html) function. I would like to run LoopSimplify first on the IR, but I do not seem to understand how to do that. There is a run(Function &F, FunctionAnalysisManager &AM) function as described on https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1LoopSimplifyPass.html and as far as I understand it I can call it on every function in my module. But for that I need a member of that class (LoopSimplify) to call it on which I do not know where to get from and also some FunctionAnalysisManager. What are they for and how do they need to look like? It is not like I can just feed it some empty constructs right?

I want to do this for the following guarantee:
"Loop pre-header insertion guarantees that there is a single, non-critical
entry edge from outside of the loop to the loop header.  This simplifies a
number of analyses and transformations, such as LICM." as described in https://llvm.org/doxygen/LoopSimplify_8h_source.html.

Comment: If you use the new pass manager (ie. your pass inherits PassInfoMixin), then your own run() receives the FunctionAnalysisManager as an argument. I seem to recall that there is a way to run another pass if it hasn't been run yet, but cannot see it now... anyway, you can call its run() until that becomes a performance problem ;)

Comment: How would I do this if PassManager is not used?

Comment: Update to a newer version of LLVM and start using the new pass manager. The legacy pass manager is a dead end at this point.

Comment: Thanks for your time and explanation. I read up on how the pass manager works and it seems as though I cannot simply integrate it in an already existing pass not based on it. Is this true though or is there some way to change an existing pass (without changing a vast amount of its structure) to be able to use that interface? Or do you know of a way to change the IR of a loop such that there always exists a pre-header (which I tried to achieve with LoopSimplify)? I could write it myself, but I would rather avoid it.

Comment: The pass manager is the most important part of the infrastructure for writing passes. LLVM makes it very simple to write and use additional passes, the price for that is that the infrastructure for the passes is important. The only reasonable way to use a pass is to set up that infrastructure. I ended up wiriting dozens of lines to instantiate at least a half-dozen classes, all to run one single pass (plus the passes it needed) But after that, I quickly started running dozens of passes.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I will have a go at it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

While I support the directions to integrate your pass into using the pass manager, nonetheless, there is a way to force LoopSimplify to run by making your pass require it.  This is also used in many of the LLVM provided passes, such as [Scalar/LoopVersioningLICM.cpp](https://llvm.org/doxygen/LoopVersioningLICM_8cpp_source.html)

```
// This header includes LoopSimplifyID as an extern
#include "llvm/Transforms/Utils.h"
...
void YourPass::getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage& AU) const {
  AU.addRequiredID(LoopSimplifyID);
}
```

Doing so will force the pass to be run prior to your pass, no need to invoke it.  However, if you need interface with this or another pass, you can request its analysis:

```
getAnalysis<LoopSimplifyPass>(F); // Where F is a function&
```

Comment: I appreciate your response. I noticed throughout the project that even though I would have really liked to rewrite my pass using the new pass manager I could not invest that much time. I solved it with `legacy::PassManager *PM = new legacy::PassManager();
    PM->add(createLoopSimplifyPass());
    PM->run(M);`